# How to transform a gameObject to a desired position and return to starting position?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, position, transform, game-physics

I'm new to UnityScript and I have the following code that does a forward movement of a gameObject on "Z" axis, but needs some refinement. Let me explain.

The script runs when a GUI.Button is clicked. The gameObject starts moving...till infinity. 
I have tried to make it move till a desired pos, (e.g. an empty gameObject pos) but didn't work at all.

How should I refine this code snippet to move the gameObject to a desired position on a first GUI.Button click and return to starting position on back click?

Furthermore, is it possible to have this movement made step by step on same GUI.Button clicks?

Here is the code snippet:

```
#pragma strict

// member variables (declared outside any function)
var startPos: Vector3;
var endPos : Vector3;
var cachedTransform : Transform;
private static var isforward = false;

// save pos before moving:
startPos = transform.position;

// make the gameObject transform, then restore the initial position when needed:
transform.position = startPos;

function Awake() {
startPos = transform.localPosition;
}

function Start() {
cachedTransform = transform;
startPos = cachedTransform.position;
}

function FixedUpdate() {

if(isforward){

var translation : float;

if (cachedTransform.position.x == endPos)
 {
  cachedTransform.position = startPos;
 }
 else
 {
    translation = Time.deltaTime * 2;
    cachedTransform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
    cachedTransform.Translate(Vector3.forward * translation);
 }
}
}
 static function doforward ()
{
    isforward = !isforward;
}
```

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily move a game object if you attach a script to it, then (in JavaScript)

```
#pragma strict    

var startPosition;

// Record the starting position when the scene loads
function Start () {
startPosition = gameObject.transform.position;

}

// Call this to move you object to wherever
function moveObject () {

var newPos = new Vector3 (10,20,0); //(where ever you need it to go) 

gameObject.transform.position = newPos;   

}

// Call this to move the object to starting position, using variable we made at start
function moveToStart () {
gameObject.transform.position = startPosition;
}
```

Then you just call those functions when you need to move the object around.

Comment: Hello @user3183542. Thank you for your response to my question. I have attached the script you've posted to a gameObject and used a GUI.Button to make it function, but nothing happens. Am I missing something here? Furthermore, in my original code snippet, how can I move gameObject back to original position?

Comment: the script wont do anything unless you call the functions in the script. Looking at your script there, I am not sure what the (isforward) variable is, and where it is coming from. It also looks like the endPos is just an empty Vector3.  also cachedTransform.position.x == endPos will never return true because endPos is a Vector3 so you need endPos.x

Comment: (isforward) variable is used to interact with another script as a GUI.Button. How can I call the functions in the script? Need to write more code? Can you provide an example code?

Comment: I would get the script and call the function like so  GameObject.Find('nameOfTheGameObject').GetComponent(YourScriptName).moveToStart();

Comment: s oyou have my sscript on your button, so where ever you are controlling the action from, in that script use what i just posted to find the game object, and its script, then call the function on it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the `Vector3.Lerp` method. This takes two vectors (points) and a float as parameters, then gives you back a point that's a fraction of the way between them. So for example, `Lerp(from, to, 0.3f)` will give you a point 30% of the way between the two points. Then once you have this, all you need to do is set your object's transform.